# Label is stop update when navigate to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am uploading file on server and showing percention on label,label is inside in the table cell, but when we navigate to another view ,its stop update, updated percentage is only show when we scroll table..

[image]

```
-(void)sendReplyOnServer:(NSMutableDictionary*)params
         withMessage:(Message*)sendMessage
           withIndex:(NSUInteger)deliveredIndex {


[self addReplyInDiscussion:sendMessage.disscussionId];

[[APIClient sharedClient] postReply:params andBlock:^(NSDictionary *responseDictionary,
                                                      NSError *error) {
    @try {

        [[DataManager sharedManager].sendMessages removeObject:sendMessage];

        if (!error){


            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary :[[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"data"] ];
            //  [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"message_status"];

            NSLog(@"%@",dict);

            Message *deliveredMessage =
            [Message modelObjectWithDictionary:dict];

            if ([[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"document"]){

                Document *doc = [Document modelObjectWithDictionary:[[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"document"]];

                if ([DataManager sharedManager].documentListArray.count == 0){
                    [DataManager loadDocumentList];
                }
                if (![DataManager sharedManager].allDocumentsList){
                    [DataManager sharedManager].allDocumentsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                }

                NSString *documentID = @"1";
                NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"documentId == %@",documentID];
                NSArray *filteredArray = [[DataManager sharedManager].documentListArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
                if (filteredArray.count != 0) {
                    Document *cameraRoll = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:0];
                    doc.parent = cameraRoll;
                    [cameraRoll.documents addObject:doc];
                }
//                    Document *cameraRoll = [[DataManager sharedManager].documentListArray objectAtIndex:1];
//                    [cameraRoll.documents addObject:doc];

                [[DataManager sharedManager].allDocumentsList addObject:doc];
                [DataManager serializeDocumentList];
                [DataManager serializeallDocumentList];

            }

            //                                                      if ([ deliveredMessage.deliveryStatus isEqualToString:@"1" ]) {
            deliveredMessage.deliveryStatus = @"2";

            //image save in file
           // deliveredMessage.attachment.image = sendMessage.attachment.image;

            if(sendMessage.attachment.image) {


                deliveredMessage.attachment.image = sendMessage.attachment.image;

                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:deliveredMessage.attachment.fileName];
                NSString *name = [url lastPathComponent];

                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
                // NSLog(@"my path == %@",path);
                NSData * binaryImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(sendMessage.attachment.image);

                [binaryImageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
            }

            // }

            if ([sendMessage.disscussionId isEqualToString:disscussionId]) {


                [self updateMessageList:deliveredMessage withIndex:deliveredIndex withSendMessage:sendMessage];

            } else if ([disscussionId isEqualToString:@""] ) {
                NSLog(@"reached in known");

                NSString *string  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataIdentifier == %@ ",sendMessage.disscussionId];

                NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:string];

                NSArray *filterArray = [[DataManager sharedManager].chatListArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

                if (filterArray.count != 0 ) {

                    DiscussionData *discussionOject = [filterArray objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSUInteger indexOfManager = [[DataManager sharedManager].chatListArray indexOfObject:discussionOject];
                    DiscussionData *managerDiscussionOject = [[DataManager sharedManager].chatListArray objectAtIndex:indexOfManager];
                    string  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"identifier == \"%@\" ",deliveredMessage.identifier];

                    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:string];
                    filterArray = [managerDiscussionOject.replies.data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

                    if ( filterArray.count != 0 ) {

                        NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];

                        NSUInteger idx = 0;
                        for ( Message *message in managerDiscussionOject.replies.data ) {
                            if ([message.identifier isEqualToString:deliveredMessage.identifier] && [message.identifier isEqualToString:message.internalBaseClassIdentifier]){
                                [indexes addIndex:idx];

                            }
                            idx ++;
                        }

                        [managerDiscussionOject.replies.data removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes ];

                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                         postNotificationName:UPDATE_REPLY_ARRAY
                         object:managerDiscussionOject];

                    }


                                            //[DataManager serializeChatList];
                }
                //This case will be handle when time is same
            }
            else {

                /* NSString *string  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataIdentifier == %@ ",sendMessage.disscussionId];

                 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:string];

                 NSArray *filterArray = [[DataManager sharedManager].chatListArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

                 if (filterArray.count != 0 ) {

                 DiscussionData *discussionOject = [filterArray objectAtIndex:0];
                 NSUInteger indexOfManager = [[DataManager sharedManager].chatListArray indexOfObject:discussionOject];
                 DiscussionData *managerDiscussionOject = [[DataManager sharedManager].chatListArray objectAtIndex:indexOfManager];


                 [DataManager serializeChatList];
                 }*/

            }



        }else {
            NSLog(@"chat reply error === %@",error.localizedDescription);
            sendMessage.deliveryStatus = @"3";

            if ([sendMessage.disscussionId isEqualToString:disscussionId]) {

                if ( repliesArray.count != 0 ) {

                    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self indexOfReplyId:sendMessage.internalBaseClassIdentifier] inSection:0];
                    //NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow inSection:0];
                    ChatDetailBaseTVC *cell = (ChatDetailBaseTVC *)[self.tableViewChatConv cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    cell.msgDeliveryStatusImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:MESSAGE_RETRY_IMAGE];
                    cell.status = @"3";

                    if (sendMessage.attachment) {
                        [cell.fileNameLabel setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", cell.messageObj.attachment.title ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        cell.progressValue = 0.0 ;
                        sendMessage.attachment.progress = @"0%";
                    }
                    [self updateContentInsetForTableView:self.tableViewChatConv animated:NO];
                    [self addReplyInDiscussion:sendMessage.disscussionId];

                }
            }


        }
    }@catch(NSException *e) {}

} showSpinner:YES showProgressView:^(float progress, NSString *messageId) {

    [self updateCellProgress:progress :messageId :sendMessage];


}];
}



-(void)updateCellProgress:(float) progress :(NSString *)messageId :(Message*)sendMessage{

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self indexOfReplyId:messageId] inSection:0];
ChatDetailAttached *cell = (ChatDetailAttached *)[self.tableViewChatConv cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.messageObj.attachment.progress =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%",progress];
NSLog(@"indx %ld == message id %@  progress == %@", (long)indexPath.row, messageId,cell.messageObj.attachment.progress);

if ([cell isKindOfClass:[ChatDetailAttached class]] &&
    [sendMessage.internalBaseClassIdentifier isEqualToString:cell.messageObj.internalBaseClassIdentifier]) {

    [cell.fileNameLabel setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@ %@",cell.messageObj.attachment.progress, cell.messageObj.attachment.title ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the cell in main thread. And use block variable when you are using block.

1. Have a variable to hold the progress, `CGFloat _progress`, `NSIndexPath *uploadIndex`,
2. When upload is clicked save the index of cell to uploadIndex.
3. Update the progress variable
4. Reload the cell in showProgressView: block

   ```
           showProgressView:^(float progress, NSString *messageId) {
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   _progress = progress; [self.tableViewChatConv reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[uploadIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
               }
           }
   ```
5. In cellForRowAtIndex , `if([indexPath isEqual:uploadIndex])` then update the progress into cell, `cell.progressValue = _progress` ;

Comment: Is uploading single image at a time or multiple image?

Answer (score 0):

put a NSTimer in viewDidLoad and set an action method on the selector of NSTimer:

And reload the tabel view in the action methode.g: [_mytableview reload];